# How to add the placeholder color in common Textfield custom class

Tags: objective-c, swift, colors, uitextfield, placeholder

I write Customclass for UITextField, I want to change all properties from one place.

I write the following code for change the placeholder color in a text field but it cants working.

Please once find my code with the following.

```
class CustomTextField:UITextField{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        /* Textfield Common Properties. */
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textAlignment = .left
        textColor = .red
        font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)
        borderStyle = .none
        if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder,
                                                            attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run your code it gives me perfect result

Comment: are you assigning this custom class to textfield using storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: Storey board but, if I change color in class it needs to reflect entire app.

Comment: in app, it particular reflects to that textfield which are subclass of CustomTextField

Comment: if your issue not solved yet then can you provide particular case in which you can't see any effect and update in question?

Comment: In my question, I give my placeholder color red but it doesn't affect that when I run my code.

self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder,
                                                            attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])

Comment: When i run your code that gives perfect result can you provide screenshot of storyboard?

Comment: Where you define custom textfield class in your project?

Comment: I created one separate class for CustomTextField, all properties are applied for that custom text field when I run my code except the placeholder color.

Comment: Make sure you don't given `user defined runtime attributes` for placeholder color for textfield then it doesn't have effect of property of custom class

Comment: Are you still getting error or solved issue?